# How can I route Smart TV traffic over OpenVPN Client in LAN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, home-networking, smart-tv

I've got a VPN Client running on Raspberry Pi in my LAN and I would like to route all the traffic from Smart TV to go through Pi and other devices use the connection without VPN. Is it possible?

My VPN provider doesn't have an application for LG WebOS 3.0 TVs

Both devices connected to the same network via Wi-Fi

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the LG Smart TV is connected via LAN directly to the Raspberry Pi: Use VPN in layer 2 mode, bridge `eth0` to `tap0` of your VPN.

If your setup (which you told us nothing about) is different: Edit question with details about the setup. Very likely it's enough to configure the RaspPi as DHCP server for the Smart TV, use an IP range different from your home IP and your VPN IP range, and setup up policy routing rules on the Raspberry. But that depends on what the Smart TV actually does. In doubt, use `wireshark` to find out.

(No, I can't give you a step-by-step description without knowing details, and in particularly I can't debug anything without access to your model of Smart TV).

Comment: TV is connected to the same network as RaspPi. Basically as you suggested I would like to use RaspPi as a Router and route all the traffic from TV over RaspPi tun0 interface

Comment: Is the TV connected via WLAN to the main router, or via LAN to the RaspPi? Is the RaspPi connected via WLAN to the main router, or also via LAN? This things make a big difference, for example, if the TV is connected via WLAN, you'll need to reconfigure your router., and then you could run the VPN on your router in the first place. We can't guess what your setup looks like, don't let us pull everything out of your nose bit by bit. And edit the question with new info, comments may not be permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Create a route in your Wi-Fi router from the televisions address to 0.0 0.0 that has the endpoint of the VPN tunnel. That should make any traffic which doesn't get an ARP response from a local device go out that tunnel if I understand the question correctly.